# Visual Studio 2022 Winforms Project reverts to Console project despite correct Csproj settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-7.0

This is a very simple, silly problem that Googling hasn't resolved.

I'm getting a console popup running a winforms project in Visual Studio 2022, in .NET 7.

I've got the csproj file setup correctly, but altering the project type via the GUI, shown here, just causes it to flip back to console project. Can anyone point to the obvious gotcha that currently doesn't appear via googling? None of my references appear to be specifically console targeted. Note the project itself runs, otherwise, as expected.

Thank you for any help offered!

Update: I bit the bullet, tried with a new project, transferred everything and added packages. The moment I succeed in running it, it reverts back to this behavior but with the new project.

Can anyone advise me a way to just hide the Console window if this can't be resolved any other way right now? Thank you!

[Project Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6np4J.png)

[image: Csproj file]

Comment: If you select Windows Application in the Output Type drop-down, what exactly happens? Does it revert immediately or when you save, build or something else?

Comment: There should be a direct correspondence between the Output Type drop-down in the project properties and the `<OutputType>` element in the project file. That there apparently isn't in your case means something is broken. Does the same thing happen with a new project? If not, I'd be inclined to create a new project and copy all the items across, assuming the number isn't too great. If the number is great then you should use source control to roll back to a known good state. If you're not using source control, this is an example of why you should.

Comment: It is source controlled, sadly it's never been correct so I can't revert. 

I get the impression that WinForms in .net 7 isn't quite as 100% as it is in net 4.8.1

Is there yet another hidden config somewhere that I've simply not seen that needs deleting/editing that you can think of? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @jmcilhinney It literally flips back as I watch - it does it that quick I couldn't screen cap it. Doesn't matter if I choose Class or Winforms either.

Comment: I've never used .NET 7 but a .NET 6 project looks exactly as you've shown and changing either the Output Type drop-down or the `<OutputType>` element also changes the other. I would try deleting the `<StartupObject>` element, changing the `<OutputType>` element to `Exe` and rebuilding, then restarting and changing the `<OutputElement>` to `WinExe` and see if the project properties changes too. If it doesn't, I'm out of ideas and recommend creating a new project, assuming that all projects of that type don't behave that way.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thank you for your time, I appreciate it. I'll be revisiting this as the project progresses. I'm hoping over the next two months, visual studio updates will help here too as I'm convinced its some bug with it. Very much obliged. WIll let you know what fixed it, if I manage it!

Comment: @jmcilhinney looks like it's doomed - transferring to a fresh new project, appeared to do, it, until I ran it. Then the same stubborn switching back bug is back. I legit think it's an actual visual studio bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer, unavailable via any search I could get so far, is shockingly simple. So anyone who has this issue, just needs to NOT include one library in their project.

Remove Microsoft.Net.TestSdk (and presumably have a separate tests project!)
[image]

This link gave me the clue, about how the Exe type was being injected by this library:

https://andrewlock.net/fixing-the-error-program-has-more-than-one-entry-point-defined-for-console-apps-containing-xunit-tests/

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people

Comment: You can also make the package conditional, only being added in Debug for example: <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.8.0" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" />