# Visual Studio 2022 keeps changing Output Type back to Console Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm working on a C# project in Visual Studio 2022 and have encountered an issue where the output type of the project keeps reverting to "Console Application". This happens even though I've set the OutputType in the .csproj file to Winexe.

[image: Selecting Windows Application Automatically Reverts Back To Console Application]

Here are the steps I've taken to try and resolve the issue:

1. Changed the Output Type to "Windows Application" through the project properties. After saving, it automatically switches back to "Console Application".
2. Checked the .csproj file directly and confirmed that the OutputType is set to Winexe.
3. Ran a repair on Visual Studio.
4. Updated Visual Studio to the latest version.
5. Cleaned and rebuilt the project.
6. Lastly, I do not have an App.config file in my project

Despite these steps, when I run the application outside of Visual Studio, a console window still appears along with the form. My Program.cs file looks like this:

```
namespace FolderMonitorService
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            // To customize application configuration such as set high DPI settings or default font,
            // see https://aka.ms/applicationconfiguration.
            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

I'd really appreciate any help or suggestions for what I can try to prevent the console window from appearing. Thank you!

Comment: Try the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76250905/10024425

Comment: Hello, will this problem also occur if you recreate a Winforms project? If only your current Winforms project has this problem, please upload your project to github for sharing, which will help you get a more targeted reply

Comment: This may be a bug of some sort.  I created a new winforms project and transferred the code over.  Now I’m not having the issue anymore.  Strange behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2022 Winforms Project reverts to Console project despite correct Csproj settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76090621/visual-studio-2022-winforms-project-reverts-to-console-project-despite-correct-c)